# Im trying to figure out the max and min of a .csv file and i cant figure out what im doing wrong

Tags: python, csv, max, min

[image]

Here is a sample of whats in the .csv file:
Entity,Code,Year,Life expectancy (years)
Afghanistan,AFG,1950,27.638
Afghanistan,AFG,1951,27.878
Afghanistan,AFG,1952,28.361
Afghanistan,AFG,1953,28.852
Afghanistan,AFG,1954,29.35
Afghanistan,AFG,1955,29.854
Afghanistan,AFG,1956,30.365
Afghanistan,AFG,1957,30.882
Afghanistan,AFG,1958,31.403
Afghanistan,AFG,1959,31.925
Afghanistan,AFG,1960,32.446
Afghanistan,AFG,1961,32.962
Afghanistan,AFG,1962,33.471
Afghanistan,AFG,1963,33.971
Afghanistan,AFG,1964,34.463
Afghanistan,AFG,1965,34.948
Afghanistan,AFG,1966,35.43
Afghanistan,AFG,1967,35.914
Afghanistan,AFG,1968,36.403
Afghanistan,AFG,1969,36.9
Afghanistan,AFG,1970,37.409
Afghanistan,AFG,1971,37.93
Afghanistan,AFG,1972,38.461
Afghanistan,AFG,1973,39.003
Afghanistan,AFG,1974,39.558
Afghanistan,AFG,1975,40.128
Afghanistan,AFG,1976,40.715
Afghanistan,AFG,1977,41.32

Comment: Post your code as test instead of image Please.

Comment: Code needs to be posted instead of an image

Answer (score 0):

you are running a for loop and then just storing each line in the form of a list in the data variable.
So, max(expectancy) does nothing in your case.
The way max works in python is max(a,b) returns the maximum value among a and b.

Anyways, for your problem.
Store the excel file into a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv ('file_name.csv')
```

now df contains the data frame with your csv content.

To find the maximum, what you can do is:

```
df.nlargest(1, 'Life expectancy')
```

//here 'Life expectancy' is the column name in your csv.

similarly for the smallest,

```
df.nsmallest(1, 'Life expectancy')
```

//here 'Life expectancy' is the column name in your csv

Answer (score 0):

You sample data probably doesn't look the way it's presented in the question. I expect (and assume) that each line has just 4 tokens.

The answer presented here may look over-complicated but what it does is allow for your CSV file to contain data (in the same assumed format) for multiple different countries and is generally robust.

```
D = dict()

with open('life_expectancy.csv') as csv:
    for line in csv:
        try:
            tokens = line.split(',')
            assert len(tokens) == 4
            v = float(tokens[3])
            D.setdefault(tokens[0], []).append(v)
        except (AssertionError, ValueError):
            pass

for k, v in D.items():
    print(f'Maximum life expectancy for {k} is {max(v):.2f}')
    print(f'Minimum life expectancy for {k} is {min(v):.2f}')
```